# Does Apache jclouds api support Miscrosoft Azure SAS

Tags: azure, jclouds

Have a project where I would like to use Apache jclouds to talk to MS Azure but need to use SAS to restrict downloads, is this supported in jclouds?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like JClouds only supports Azure Blob Shared Key Lite at the moment.

Reference: https://twitter.com/andrewthegaul/status/775565970236506112

Answer (score 0):

I was just investigating this myself and it looks like as of the JClouds v2.1.0 release this is now supported.